# How to prevent displaying contextmenuStrip?

Tags: c#

How can I prevent displaying dataGridView contextMenuStrip if no rows has been selected ?

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe to the [ToolStripDropDown.Opening Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown.opening.aspx), and you can cancel it.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        this.Load += new EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        this.InitializeComponent();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("col1");
        dt.Columns.Add("col2");
        dt.Rows.Add(new string[] { "test", "test" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new string[] { "test", "test" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new string[] { "test", "test" });

        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        this.dataGridView1.ContextMenuStrip.Opening += new CancelEventHandler(this.ContextMenuStrip_Opening);            
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
    }

    private void ContextMenuStrip_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count == 0)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i added the contextMenustrip using the dataGridView properties

Comment: does not work, contextMenuStrip appears also although i did not select a row

Comment: Are you subscribing to the event? The code above definitely works.

Comment: Could you show the code that you implemented that isn't working?

Comment: this.dataGridView1.ContextMenuStrip.Opening += new CancelEventHandler(ContextMenuStrip_Opening); within the constructor, or create the event through the designer properties.

Comment: See my updates. When a DataGridView is loaded, it automatically has the first row selected if there are rows. After the form loads, clear the selection. See above. On the initial load of the form, the menu won't open, and then once you select a row, the menu will open.

Comment: does not work, the menu appear every here I right click the mouse on the datagridview although i don't select any row !

Comment: Not sure what to tell you otherwise. If I were you, create a new winforms application, drop a datagridview on it, and then put this code on the code file, it should work ...